# I am implementing file picker on android 11 and getting uri.getPath() in form of "/document/msf:1334"

Tags: java, android

1.This method gets executed successfully but it returns null.

```java
      private String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
          Cursor cursor = null; 
           try {
              String[] proj = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA };
              cursor context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,proj, null, 
               null, null); 
              int column_index = 
               cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA);   
               cursor.moveToFirst(); 
              return cursor.getString(column_index); 
               }
              catch (Exception e) { 
                 Log.e("TAG", "getRealPathFromURI Exception : " + 
                  e.toString()); 
                 return ""; 
               } finally
                 { if (cursor != null) 
                     {   
                      cursor.close(); 
                     } 
                 }
           }
```

2. onActivityresult method.

```java
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                     Intent resultData) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultData);
            if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_FILE
                    && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // The result data contains a URI for the document or directory 
                // that the user selected.
                Uri uri = null;
                if (resultData != null) {
                            uri = resultData.getData();
                            Log.e( "Error!llllllllll", "nullll  "+uri.getPath());
                String path = getRealPathFromURI(s_activity,uri);
                Log.e( "Error!llllllllll", "nullll  "+path);
                
                   }

              }
            }
```

Comment: You did not tell what you want and what you are doing. Or which errors you get. Please wrote a normal post.

Comment: I am trying to get retrieve the path of file from uri received in

Comment: @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 Intent resultData) {

Comment: ???? Please edit your post to make it a normal post. And tell more than you did now. Dont use comments. Write a good post as nothing is clear.

Comment: but in the place of path i am getting the “/document/msf:1334”